# Where is a way to run javascript code remotely?

Tags: javascript, remote-access, ecmascript-5

I want to be able to run live code remotely. Therefor, I want to be able to run some arbitrary code on machine A and then, transfer some of that code to machine B and continue running it from machine B.

I find out that I can get the source code of any function via `fn.toString()`.

Example:

```
var foo = function(a, b) { return a + b; }

console.log(foo.toString()); // prints "function (a, b) { return a + b; }"
```

So far so good, but what happens in this case?

```
var bar = (function() {
    var x = 5;

    return function(a) { return a + x; }
})();

console.log(bar.toString()); // prints "function (a) { return a + x; }"
```

In this case there is no way to get the variable `x`, so I can't run it on a remote machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: define `x` in outer scope of `console.log(bar.toString());`

Comment: @evc I have no control over the `bar` function. It can be changed by other parties.

Comment: What do you mean by "run live code remotely"?  What is your end goal here?  You may be able to set a breakpoint in your browser's debugger possibly.

Comment: @MosheSimantov Curious, what exactly do you mean by your title "Run JavaScript Code Remotely"? Where are you running it from? A server with some kind of API that communicates with client-side code?

Comment: I want to be able to run some arbitrary on machine A and then, transfer some of that code to machine B and continue from machine B. Think about it as a real cloud server.

Comment: @MosheSimantov Is this client-side as with browsers or server-side like with node.js?

Comment: Server-side, Node.js.

Comment: Instead of trying to use `.toString()` on various functions, I suggest putting the code you want to run into its own file.  Then you can load in that file as a string and transfer it as you want.  Maybe you can make a request to the 2nd server and send the file like you would a file upload (like in a form).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). In addition, your question is too broad. What you need is the same program on both machines A and B, and a way to capture the state of the entire program (including the [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter)) at any given point of time, transfer it from machine A to machine B, and then resume execution on machine B. There's no way to do this without writing your own JavaScript interpreter, which is out of the scope of an answer on StackOverflow. Hence, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your second function returns the following as a string

```
function(a) { return a + x; }
```

is because you have an anonymous function that returns the function above. "bar" is then defined as that function, and not the anonymous one. Also, given that your returned function is localized, then you cannot run it verbatim. Instead, you can use the variable that holds it, "bar()", and once it runs, it will know the value of x.

Comment: The point isn't what the variable `x`. The point is to be able to transfer the code to a remote server and run it from there.

Comment: What I said was valid. You cannot take the string value of "bar" and run it in another environment as-is. You would need the whole text of what creates "bar". That is why what you demo'd above is called an anonymous function. Its anonymity hides a local scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you do need is a js runner, but AFAIK there is none yet(?)

What it should be:
You would have a computer called "a runner" which is a slave and only waiting for code to be pushed on it. Another master computer/process would have access to this slave runner and push a block of code to be executed.

Right now, to what I know, there is no way to easily split your code and just run it remotely but one way I would see to achieve this would be to set up an RPC server which would get the source code as an argument and execute that one using `exec()`. You could, for instance, do this using a JSON-RPC server. The JSON-RPC client would then post the block of code and the client return the result as a JSON object.

But this would only give you back a JSON object and you still have to serialize your function or code to be run remotely. It should, however, be good enough for most of the use. I bet there should be [serverless](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/true-er-functional-programming-on-serverless-nodejs-e532079b40d/) lambda-like services doing this even with a regular POST i.e. you would post source code to this service and get the result in the response.

I hope there will be "one day" a kind of remote worker where instead of running the code in another thread "locally" that one would be run "remotely". Please comment if you ever saw such a "remote worker".